# Matplolib fixing EXACT size of pdf file

Tags: matplotlib

I have a code that creates bar plots from a file. I save each plot in a pdf file with a fixed size that I set using rcParams (Landscape A4 format):

```py
 fig_size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]
 fig_size[0] = 11  # Landscape A4 format inches
 fig_size[1] = 8 
 plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = fig_size
```

This is the code to save the plot as pdf.

```py
plt.savefig(filename, bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0.5, transparent=True, dpi=300)
```

I have tried dpi=100, dpi=600 with no change.

I have about 40 pdf files. However, the size of those pdf slightly varies from 10:35 x 8:36 to almost 10:47x 8:47 inches.
I am talking of the size of the page itself not the disk space that I understand depends on the number of pixel used to plot the file. My files are between 13-17 kb... and that is ok.

What is not ok, is that I can't combine the pdf files in a report as the sizes of the pdf pages do not match.

How can I set up the size of the pdf page to be exactly the same?

below a reproducible script:

```py
"For StackOverFlow"


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

SMALL_SIZE = 9
MEDIUM_SIZE = 14
BIGGER_SIZE = 18 #28

plt.rc('font', size=SMALL_SIZE)          # controls default text sizes
plt.rc('axes', titlesize=SMALL_SIZE)     # fontsize of the axes title
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=MEDIUM_SIZE)    # fontsize of the x and y labels
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('legend', fontsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # legend fontsize
plt.rc('axes', titlesize=BIGGER_SIZE)

#x1 = [14, 10, 61, 15, 22]
#y1 = [-10, -2, 1, 8, 12]

#x1 = [0, 1.4, 1.47, 2.3, 2.6]
#y1 = [-1.51, -0.03, 0.04, 0.92, 1.23]

x1=[0.795466667, 1.02, 1.12, 1.155, 1.22, 1.459, 1.47, 1.81]
y1=[-1.50, -0.77, -0.45, -0.34, -0.13, 0.64, 0.68, 1.77]

barWidth = 1.2

r1 = [1.5* i for i in range(0, len(y1))]

fig_size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]
fig_size[0] = 11 #fig_size[0] = 11.69
fig_size[1] = 8 #fig_size[1] = 8.27
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = fig_size

plt.margins(0.005, 0.005)

plt.bar(r1,y1, align='center', color='#9E0032', width=barWidth)

plt.xlabel('Z Code', fontweight='bold')

plt.ylabel('\n Z Value', fontweight='bold') 

# Create names on the x-axis
plt.xticks(r1, x1, fontweight='bold')

plt.yticks(fontweight='bold')

title = "Specimen1"

plt.title(title, fontweight='bold')

filename = title + ".pdf"


#plt.savefig(filename, bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0.5, transparent=True, dpi=300)
plt.savefig(filename, pad_inches=0.5, transparent=True, dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: `bbox_inches="tight"` crops the figure (that's its purpose). So if you don't want that, remove it.

Comment: @JohnHennig Would my comment above not suffice as answer?

Comment: @John Mind that `bbox_inches="tight"` is different from `tight_layout`. The former changes the figure size that gets exported, the latter rearranges the elements within the figure.

Comment: Passing remark: A4 is not 8" × 11" — if you set the figsize like that and **physically print on an A4 sheet** you will be disappointed...

Comment: Many thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest and John Hennig. I removed 'bbox_inches="tight" ' but when I test the script on the entire input file, I have some files which size are 11 x 8, some 10.32 x 8.15, some 10.46 x 8.15 ....The sizes still vary. Also the titles of the figures are different some long, some short and the number of data points also differs by plot. I am still unsure how to fix this problem using Matplotlib. ** I would like all pdf pages to have the same size**. For now, I use AdobeAcrobat Pro to fix it but it is painful to do it one file at a time. Thank you.

Comment: Well, if I run the code in the question, I get a 8 by 11 inches pdf, which is expected, because this is the size set and not `"tight"` option is used. Feel free to provide a [mcve] of a case which is **un**expected.

Comment: Again, you were correct!!! I had to track the code again and again and there was a last 'bbox_inches="tight"  hanging around. Now, once I don't have the title longer than 66 characters, everything is 11 x 8. Many Many Thanks